# How to pass user defined username from IBM Websphere Application server to AS400 MQ server for authentication?

Tags: java, jms, websphere, ibm-mq, ibm-midrange

I am having an issue with connecting AS400 MQ Local Queue, its rejecting with code JMSWMQ2013.

My appserver has a *username* as *mquser@mydomain.com* but in AS400 I am not able to give the specified username in MQ Object Authority.

Is there any way to connect to the queue defined in AS400 machine from Websphere Appserver on windows machine?

Below is the error i am facing while connecting:

```
FFDC Exception:com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException SourceId:com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedQueueConnection.createConnection ProbeId:116 Reporter:com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedQueueConnection@db6f33e4
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'TESTQMGR' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'AS400T(1416)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.

Root cause:  

JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:204)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to define separate J2C authentication alias and map it to the connection factory.  What does it mean that `My appserver has a username as mquser@mydomain.com`?

Check this page [2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED Connecting to WebSphere MQ](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21636093) for more details:

> The two most likely reasons why the connection is refused by MQ are as follows:
>
> ```
> 1. The user identifier passed across the client connection from the application 
>    server to MQ is not known on the server where the MQ queue manager is running,
>    is not authorised to connect to MQ, or is longer than 12 characters and has
>    been truncated.
>    For queue managers running on Windows, the following error might be seen in 
>    the MQ error logs for this scenario:
>    AMQ8075: Authorization failed because the SID for entity 'wasuser' 
>    cannot be obtained.
>    For UNIX no entry in the MQ error logs would be seen by default.
>    See technote MQS_REPORT_NOAUTH environment variable can be used 
>    to better diagnose return code 2035 for details of enabling error log 
>    entries on all platforms.
> 2. The user identifier passed across the client connection from the 
>    application server to MQ is a member of the 'mqm' group on the server 
>    hosting the MQ queue manager, and a Channel Authentication Record (CHLAUTH) 
>    exists that blocks administrative access to the queue manager. 
>    WebSphere MQ configures a CHLAUTH record by default in WebSphere MQ 
>    Version 7.1 and later that blocks all MQ admins from connecting 
>    as a client to the queue manager.
>    The following error in the MQ error logs would be seen for 
>    this scenario: AMQ9777: Channel was blocked
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem we are facing is with AS400 machine, the user application having is more than 12 and also there is no option available in MQ for authentication record because it is Websphere MQ 7.0. i think its something to do with grant authority. But one thing i noted for one queue its connecting which i am using for listener purpose. But for other queues which i am trying to put message is having issue with error code 2035 error. Please let me know if you have any solution. Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

You indicate in a later comment that you are using MQ V7.0 on AS/400.

Your question details that you have a user ID mquser@mydomain.com which will not be recognised by the AS/400 O/S.

Therefore you are looking for a way to assign a user ID for the connection which you are making from the App Server on Windows so that it can run using a recognised user ID on the AS/400 queue manager.

Since you are pre-V7.1, you cannot use CHLAUTH rules, so your choices are

- Write a security exit to do it (or buy/download one)
- Give this connection its own channel and set the MCAUSER on the SVRCONN to something that is known and recognised by the AS/400 O/S. In this case, please also make sure you have some form of authentication, e.g. SSL/TLS so that no-one else can use this channel.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, *Username* and *password* can be passed with `setStringProperty` on `MQQueueConnectionFactory`

```
  MQQueueConnectionFactory mqConFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
  mqConFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, "username");
  mqConFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, "password");

  //other configs
  mqConFactory.setHostName("MQ_HOST");
  mqConFactory.setChannel("MQ_CHANNEL");//communications link
  mqConFactory.setPort("MQ_PORT");
  mqConFactory.setQueueManager("MQ_MANAGER");//service provider
  mqConFactory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
```

Needed imports:

```
  import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory;
  import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;
```

Dependency jars:

```
  compile('com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allclient:9.0.5.0')
```

Part of code took from this [page](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2015/11/11/specifying-user-name-password-mq-application/)